# Why doesn't IllegalAccessError have two-argument constructor?

Tags: java

The IllegalAccessError class has two constructors, `IllegalAccessError()` and `IllegalAccessError(String s)`.

Why doesn't IllegalAccessError have a two-argument constructor like `IllegalAccessError(String s, Throwable cause)`?

Comment: You should not raise this error, this error is only raised by the JVM itself. In fact, **you should never raise a throwable that ends with Error** as they are not for usage unless you're working on the JVM itself.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's quite true; the most notable exception that comes to mind is `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 5):

`IllegalAccessError` itself is the ultimate root cause of an error. That is why it does not take any `Throwable cause`.